# Wialon WLP format

Tags: c#, json

Previously I created a view in our old system to expose the data needed to create new vehicles in Wialon.  I've now created a little c# app to turn each vehicle into a WLP file for easy importing.  WLP is a JSON file that may or may not contain sections.  I got the template for mine by exporting some vehicles and looking at the files.

When I try to load a file I have created, I get the error **Upload Failed**.  When I contacted helpdesk they gave back a copy of the file missing all but the top section.  When I asked further, I was given a link to the export/import WLP page, that indicates Yes, you can import or export WLP files.  Nol code samples or file spec.

**File A**
Exported from the system.  Password and unique censored.  Pretty print

```
{
    "type": "avl_unit",
    "version": "b4",
    "mu": 0,
    "general": {
        "n": "Hino",
        "uid": "*******************",
        "uid2": "",
        "ph": "",
        "ph2": "",
        "psw": "*******",
        "hw": "FleetLogix Import"
    },
    "counters": {
        "cfl": 274,
        "cnm": 102973,
        "cneh": 0,
        "cnkb": 0
    },
    "profile": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "n": "vehicle_class",
            "v": "empty_vehicle"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "n": "registration_plate",
            "v": "CS83YR"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "n": "brand",
            "v": "HINO"
        }
    ]
}
```

**File B**
Generated by my code

```
{
    "type": "avl_unit",
    "version": "b4",
    "mu": 0,
    "general": {
        "n": "Hino",
        "uid": "*****************",
        "uid2": "",
        "ph": "",
        "ph2": "",
        "psw": "******",
        "hw": "FleetLogix Import"
    },
    "counters": {
        "cfl": 274,
        "cnm": "102980",
        "cneh": 0,
        "cnkb": 0
    },
    "profile": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "n": "vehicle_class", 
    "v": "empty_vehicle"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "n": "registration_plate", 
    "v": "CS83YR"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "n": "brand", 
    "v": "HINO"
}
    ]
}
```

At this point the only real difference I can see is the indenting of the Profile collection.  Only non-blank entries are added and numbered.

Any Wialon dev's watching?

**Edit**

Below is the method used to export to file. A Unit is a c# class holding datafields.

```
public bool CreateWlpFile(Unit unit)
{
    string prefix = "UnitWlpFileCreator.CreateWlpFile";
    Console.WriteLine($"{prefix}({unit.UnitName})");
    bool returnVal = true;
    string template = _config.GetValue<string>("wialon:unitTemplate");

    string source = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), template);
    string initial = File.ReadAllText(source);


    Console.WriteLine($"{prefix} Building profile string");
    int profileId = 1;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine("{");
    sb.AppendFormat("\t\"id\": {0},", profileId).AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine("\t\"n\": \"vehicle_class\", ");
    sb.AppendLine("\t\"v\": \"empty_vehicle\"");
    sb.AppendLine("},");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit.VIN))
    {
        profileId++;
        sb.AppendLine("{");
        sb.AppendLine($"\t\"id\": {profileId},");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"n\": \"vin\", ");
        sb.AppendLine($"\t\"v\": \"{unit.VIN}\"");
        sb.AppendLine("},");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit.UnitRego))
    {
        profileId++;
        sb.AppendLine("{");
        sb.AppendLine($"\t\"id\": {profileId},");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"n\": \"registration_plate\", ");
        sb.AppendLine($"\t\"v\": \"{unit.UnitRego}\"");
        sb.AppendLine("},");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit.Brand))
    {
        profileId++;
        sb.AppendLine("{");
        sb.AppendLine($"\t\"id\": {profileId},");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"n\": \"brand\", ");
        sb.AppendLine($"\t\"v\": \"{unit.Brand}\"");
        sb.AppendLine("},");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit.Model))
    {
        profileId++;
        sb.AppendLine("{");
        sb.AppendLine($"\t\"id\": {profileId},");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"n\": \"model\", ");
        sb.AppendLine($"\t\"v\": \"{unit.Model}\"");
        sb.AppendLine("},");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit.Year))
    {
        profileId++;
        sb.AppendLine("{");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"id\": {profileId},");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"n\": \"year\", ");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"v\": \"{unit.Year}\"");
        sb.AppendLine("},");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit.Color))
    {
        profileId++;
        sb.AppendLine("{");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"id\": {profileId},");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"n\": \"color\", ");
        sb.AppendLine("\t\"v\": \"{unit.Color}\"");
        sb.AppendLine("},");
    }

    string profileFieldsJsonFragment = sb.ToString().Trim().TrimEnd(',');

    Console.WriteLine($"{prefix} Profile");
    Console.WriteLine(profileFieldsJsonFragment);

    Console.WriteLine($"{prefix} Replacing Tokens");
    string r1 = initial.Replace("$unitName$", unit.UnitName);
    string r2 = r1.Replace("$uniqueId$", unit.UniqueId);
    string r3 = r2.Replace("$odo$", unit.Odometer);
    string r4 = r3.Replace("$profileFields$", profileFieldsJsonFragment);


    Console.WriteLine($"{prefix} Minifying Json String");
    string finalOutput = null;
    try
    {
        // actually treat the string as json
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(r4);
        finalOutput = json.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
    }
    catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Problem parsing json string");
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception Type: {ex.GetType()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Target Site: {ex.TargetSite}");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        returnVal = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception Type: {ex.GetType()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Target Site: {ex.TargetSite}");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        returnVal = false;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{prefix} Writing Output");
    string outputFilename = $"{unit.UnitName}_{unit.UnitRego}.wlp";

    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(outputFilename, finalOutput);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception Type: {ex.GetType()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Target Site: {ex.TargetSite}");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        returnVal = false;
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: I'm quite confident I can extract data and put it in  a file.  The question is about the file format and a way past the opaque error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in field type.  My local json tools said the field was correctly formatted.  Was not schema aware to know it needed to be an int, not a string.  The server was rejecting but not passing a meaningful error.